# Efficient way to fill NumPy array for independent entries

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I fill matrix `K` where each entry is a function applied to two entries of array `x` using a double for-loop:

```
K = np.zeros((x.shape[0],x.shape[0]), dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[0]):
        K[i,j] = f(x[i],x[j])
```

Matrix is 10,000 by 10,000 and takes very long to calculate. Is there a more efficient way with NumPy? The function is a Gaussian kernel:

```
def gaussian(a,b,sigma):
    vec = a-b
    return np.exp(- np.dot(vec,vec)/(2*sigma**2))
```

I set `sigma` before calculating. Array `x` is of shape (10000, 8) so the scalar product in the Gaussian is between two vectors of dimension 8.

Comment: It would be useful to provide a real example. Which kind of function do you want to apply? Please give example of function/input/output.

Comment: There is. It is called `np.fromfunction`. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html

Comment: I have added some details for the function.
`np.fromfunction` only takes the coordinates as input though, doesn't it? Not rows from another array.

Comment: @user2640045, it's easy to mis-read `fromfunction`.  It creates a set of indicies/grid points, and calls the function **just once** with the whole set.  It is not an iterator (or compiler).

Comment: As long as `f` only accepts scalar values (or smaller dimensional arrays) there isn't much you can do to avoid the loops.  The expensive step is evaluating that function many times.  To get `numpy` efficiency the function has to accept whole-arrays, which fortunately yours does.

Comment: @hpaulj I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single `for` loop together with broadcasting. This requires to change the implementation of the `gaussian` function to accept 2D inputs:

```py
def gaussian(a,b,sigma):
    vec = a-b
    return np.exp(- np.sum(vec**2, axis=-1)/(2*sigma**2))


K = np.zeros((x.shape[0],x.shape[0]), dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    K[i] = gaussian(x[i:i+1], x)
```

Theoretically you could accomplish this even without any `for` loop, again by using broadcasting, but here an intermediary array of size `len(x)**2 * x.shape[1]` will be created which might run out of memory for your array sizes:

```py
K = gaussian(x[None, :, :], x[:, None, :])
```

Comment: thanks! that has made it a lot faster!
The computer I am using has enough RAM to cope with the full broadcasting method up to about 30,000**3 for float32 it seems.